# How to convert raw Join Query into Magento Join Query

Tags: orders

Here is my query..

$query = "select * from sales_order AS so join sales_order_item as soi WHERE so.entity_id=soi.order_id AND so.status IN('pending','processing') AND soi.item_id NOT IN ( select shp.order_item_id from sales_shipment_item shp)";

Answer (score 0):

Following code based on the class dependency:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
) {
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
```

Inside your custom function use below code:

```
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
$salesOrderTable = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('sales_order');
$salesOrderItemTable = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('sales_order_item');
$salesShipmentItemTable = $this->resourceConnection->getTableName('sales_shipment_item');
$sql = $connection->select()
        ->from(['so' => $salesOrderTable])
        ->join(['soi' => $salesOrderItemTable], 'main_table.entity_id = soi.order_id')
        ->join(['shp' => $salesShipmentItemTable], 'soi.item_id = shp.order_item_id')
        ->where('so.status IN('pending','processing')');
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

I guess you don't need last clause if inner join works for you. Correct me if I'm wrong.